# SystemStackError: stack level too deep while upgrading from rails 6.0 to 6.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, rails-upgrade

While I am upgrading my rails application with ruby 2.7.4 and Moving form rails 6.0 to 6.1.4  I am facing issue while running command

```
bin/rails app:update
```

I am also adding few lines of errors

```
    force  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb
   identical  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config.ru
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
   identical  bin/setup
   identical  bin/spring
   identical  bin/yarn
       rails  active_storage:update
rails aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Comment: Include the entire error message, please.

Comment: nrails aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/Linux/All_Rails/rail_update/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/Linux/All_Rails/rail_update/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/Linux/All_Rails/rail_update/bin/spring:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/Linux/All_Rails/rail_update/bin/spring:4:in `tap'
/home/Linux/All_Rails/rail_update/bin/spring:4:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => app:update => app:update:active_storage
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Appologies for delayed update @idmean